# What technique do I use to get text into each individual tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, logic

I have been stuck on this for ages, here is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://mihaifrentiu.com/wp-content/themes/mf/js/jquery_1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html, div, ul, li, a {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body {
                font-family:arial;
                font-size:12px;
                color:#000000;

            }
            .clear {
                clear:both;
            }
            ul {
                list-style:none;
                position:relative;
                z-index:2;
                top:1px;
                display:table;
                border-left:5px solid #808080;
            }
            ul li {
                float:left;
            }
            ul li a {
                background:#000000;
                color:#000000;
                display:block;
                padding:6px 15px;
                text-decoration:none;
                border-right:100px solid #000000;
                border-top:1px solid #000000;
                border-right:3px solid #808080;
            }
            ul li a.selected {
                border-bottom:1px solid #808080;
                color:#000000;
                background:#808080;
            }
            h1 {
                display:block;
                width:600px;
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:200px 0;
                color:#000000;
            }
            #navigation {
                width:602px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #content {
                width:600px;
                margin:0 auto;
                height:200px;
                background:#ffffff;
                border:1px solid #000000;
                z-index:1;
                text-align:center;
                padding:10px 0;
            }
            #logo {
                width:600px;
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:10px 0;
                text-align:right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(1);" id="tab1"><font color="white">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(2);" id="tab2"><font color="white">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(3);" id="tab3"><font color="white">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(4);" id="tab4"><font color="white">Tab 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(5);" id="tab5"><font color="white">Tab 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
       <div id="content">
            <p id="content_changer">You have selected Tab 1</p>
            <p>See the page source for full code</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#navigation ul a').click(function() {
                    $('#navigation ul a').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    $('#content_changer').html('You have selected ' + $(this).html());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can not figure out how to get one of these tabs menu thing to work, I have tried so many different methods but nothing will work.

Comment: Since you're using jquery, have you tried jquery ui tabs? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

It's not very good code, but it works for me. The only problem is that the `#content` text is set to font color white, so you can't see it, though it is there.

You should avoid `font` tags, as they are badly out of date, as well as inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code. I found that the text is written  `#content_changer` element, but its white colored.
Here's how you can solve it.

Add the following css rule

```
#content_changer{
    color:#000;
}
```

Change the `$(this).html()` to `$(this).text()`.
That much should do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your JS, but in your CSS. Font color is white on the links in the navigation, which means it will be invisible on the content area. Also, using  is deprecated and you need to set content-area color to black.

Here is a working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ftyy/

Differences are these:

```
#content_changer {
color: black;
}
ul li a {
color: white;
}
```

and no font-color in html.